# Export information from text file in linux with bash script

Tags: bash, file, edit

I have this specific file:

```
Client 1: MAC 00:03:52:49:99:55
 First      : Fri Nov  7 09:50:11 2014
 Last       : Fri Nov  7 09:51:06 2014
--
 Client 1: MAC 00:03:52:04:88:55
 First      : Fri Nov  7 09:51:44 2014
 Last       : Fri Nov  7 09:51:44 2014
--
 Client 2: MAC 00:03:52:49:99:55
 First      : Fri Nov  7 10:50:10 2014
 Last       : Fri Nov  7 10:50:10 2014
--
 Client 3: MAC 00:03:52:04:66:55
 First      : Fri Nov  7 09:51:30 2014
 Last       : Fri Nov  7 09:51:30 2014
--
```

From this file with many duplicate items like to create a new file like this:

```
00:03:52:49:99:55
First      : Fri Nov  7 09:50:11 2014
Last       : Fri Nov  7 09:51:06 2014
First      : Fri Nov  7 09:50:11 2014
Last       : Fri Nov  7 09:51:06 2014
00:03:52:04:88:55
First      : Fri Nov  7 09:51:44 2014
Last       : Fri Nov  7 09:51:44 2014
00:03:52:04:66:55
First      : Fri Nov  7 09:51:30 2014
Last       : Fri Nov  7 09:51:30 2014
```

How i can search with Bash Script the File with a For-Loop ? Important that the loop don't make more then 1 entry for the MAC-address. The MAC should be unique.

yes i have tried all this day :/

```
#!/bin/bash
array=$(cat Kismet-20141107-09-48-19-1.nettxt | grep Client -A 3 | grep -v Manuf)
echo "Array size: ${#array[@]}"
echo "Array items:"
for item in ${array[*]}
    do
    if [ $item -eq 3 ]; then
         echo "$array[$item]"
    fi
done
```

no it's not a requirement to use bash.. if you have other tools i will try it!

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Are you stuck with anything in particular? Is it a requirement that you do this using native bash functionality or could you use a tool such as awk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
Shell> cat test1
#!/bin/bash

MACS=(`grep Client file|awk '{print $4}'|sort|uniq|xargs`)

for i in `echo ${MACS[*]}`; do
        echo $i
        grep $i file -A 2 | grep -vE 'MAC|--'
done
Shell> cat file
Client 1: MAC 00:03:52:49:99:55
 First      : Fri Nov  7 09:50:11 2014
 Last       : Fri Nov  7 09:51:06 2014
--
 Client 1: MAC 00:03:52:04:88:55
 First      : Fri Nov  7 09:51:44 2014
 Last       : Fri Nov  7 09:51:44 2014
--
 Client 2: MAC 00:03:52:49:99:55
 First      : Fri Nov  7 10:50:10 2014
 Last       : Fri Nov  7 10:50:10 2014
--
 Client 3: MAC 00:03:52:04:66:55
 First      : Fri Nov  7 09:51:30 2014
 Last       : Fri Nov  7 09:51:30 2014
--
```

Output:

```
Shell> ./test1
00:03:52:04:66:55
 First      : Fri Nov  7 09:51:30 2014
 Last       : Fri Nov  7 09:51:30 2014
00:03:52:04:88:55
 First      : Fri Nov  7 09:51:44 2014
 Last       : Fri Nov  7 09:51:44 2014
00:03:52:49:99:55
 First      : Fri Nov  7 09:50:11 2014
 Last       : Fri Nov  7 09:51:06 2014
 First      : Fri Nov  7 10:50:10 2014
 Last       : Fri Nov  7 10:50:10 2014
```